# Swagger-Codegen .Net-3.5 - how to remove default parameters in generated code

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate c# client for a rest api. Since my c# consumer is built in .Net framework version 3.5, I am using the below command to generate c# client libraries using Swagger-Codegen CLI

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l csharp -i "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Service.json" --api-package Api.Profiles --model-package Models.Profiles -DModelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName=My.Profiles --additional-properties targetFramework=v3.5
```

Though the client libraries are successfully generated with target framework V3.5, I can see 'default' parameters in most of the constructors and methods. Since default parameters are not supported in .Net V3.5, I am seeing errors during build. I can remove them manually, but would like to know if it can be handled in code generation.

Eg.,

```
public MyConstructor(int? id = default(int?))
{
  this.Id = id;
}
```